# How to trigger build with Continous Integration in TFS 2010 only if certain builds are not queued?

Tags: tfs, build, queue, continuous-integration

I'm struggling with the following issue.
Let's say we have solutions A, B, C and following dependencies:

> A          (no dependencies)
>
> B -> A     (B uses A)
>
> C -> A,B   (C uses A and B)

I've created builds with batched continous integration, so whenever I check in any of those solution, next builds are triggered.

Now, whenever I check-in A, B, C solutions, the build queue looks like that:

> A
>
> B
>
> C
>
> C (triggered after build B is Done)
>
> B (triggered after build A is Done)
>
> C (triggered after second build B is done)

but that takes too much time. Is there any way to make them trigger like that:

> A
>
> B (disregarded due to the fact that build A is in the queued and it's
>   not necessarily to build it)
>
> C (disregarded due to the fact that build A is in the queued and it's
>   not necessarily to build it)
>
> B (triggered from build A)
>
> C (triggered from build B)

so that there are no duplicated builds in the queue. What about multiple user check-in's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box. You would have to write an activity that checked that the other build was not running before doing a build.

Alternatively you seam to be in a bind. Why do you not publish each dependency as a Nuget package and take a dependency on that instead. Then you don't need a chained build.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a [Rolling Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190718(v=vs.100).aspx#reason-batched-ci).

Team Foundation Server will collect any builds that are queued while a build is running and run them as one build. If that build fails, the build will be run separately to determine which build is the culprit.

Comment: That doesn't help, becouse build B is still being triggereda after check-in - I'm building projects in parralel to save some time. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong.